# GT-N5100: Random apps crashing suddenly

Tags: samsung, crashes

So, I got this problem with my Android GT-N5100 (running Android 4.4.2). It keeps crashing apps suddenly and randomly. I flashed it with Samsung's official firmware and since then it keeps like that. I know that if I factory reset it, it's gonna be happening the same way.

I was thinking about flashing Cyanogenmod but my device is currently unsupported. That is.. There are only nightly builds available for it at this moment, and it takes too many hacks to do so, then I'm not risking it. I thought also that it could be a memory overflow problem... Maybe.. But every time I open the window manager it seems to have plenty of memory left. I use to kill apps to avoid that, but no matter what... You got it.

Would someone PLEASE link me to a stable firmware free of bugs like that or tell me what the hell is going on and how can I fix this problem??

I'm tired of it... Believe me.

Comment: Have you tried clearing the `dalvik-cache`? It might be that the update did not clear it and it's now halfway broken.

Comment: @GiantTree, not just yet, but I flashed a fresh install of the ROM to the device. Does that really matter? I'll try that anyway then I'll report back. Thanks.

Comment: @GiantTree, forgot to mention... Can I do that via the stock recovery mode or do I have to install CWM Recovery? I just reset my device into recovery mode and wiped the "cache" partition, but I don't know exactly if that's the `dalvik-cache` partition.
Sorry, I'm pretty new to this.

Comment: Wiping the `cache` partition in stock recoveries usually also wipes the `dalvik-cache`. If not, only a factory reset might help.

Comment: Wait: You've flashed a ROM (different than the one running before) and didn't clear cache and Dalvik cache? Yes, that often causes apps to crash. Clear both, if possible. Wiping cache is always possible, even from stock recovery; for Dalvik, that's a different case.

Comment: @Izzy, so **I do need** to install CWM Recovery in order to clean up the `dalvik-cache`? Erm... I do not know much about unlocking the bootloader, so could you give me some directions to that if necessary? Thanks.

Comment: @GiantTree Are you sure that wiping cache ( `/cache`) also wipes Dalvik cache (`/data/dalvik-cache`)? Then why are that two different menu items in custom recoveries? A factory-reset wipes both, yes. X_Hunter: Did wiping cache help? If not: is your device rooted? As for the boot loader: sorry, I'm not familiar with Samsung devices. But you could watch out for a "temporary CWM" (one that is not permanently installed), and use that to wipe Dalvik cache. Also see [this XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2251033) ;)

Comment: @Izzy It depends on the recovery. My S3 wiped `dalvik-cache` together with `cache`, but I don't know about his phone in particular.

Comment: Thanks, @GiantTree – good to know. I never dug into that, but also never heard either report (whether it does or not). Yours is the first ;)

Comment: @GiantTree and Izzy, it's still happening now, but not so often as before. I had to wait some days to test the device, but it is still happening. Mostly with Google Play Games, Play Store, WhatsApp and Chrome. (which are the apps I use most.)
I even did a factory reset. Maybe it's memory related then?